# Angular4: How to pass array of objects to function

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

I want to pass array of objects to function in **Angular 4**

**Call Function:**

```
this.clickCounter(this.persons);
```

**My Array:**

```
persons=[
  {name:"ali",mobile:"1234"},
  {name:"ahmed",mobile:"1234"},
  {name:"noha",mobile:"1234"},
  {name:"esam",mobile:"1234"},
]
```

**Function**

```
clickCounter(x:any[]) {
  console.log("data in function " + x);
}
```

**console:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlJCa.png

Comment: seems to be ok, do you get any error?

Comment: Are you really asking how to get that array from an http service (web site) in your component?

Comment: Either proceed with type `any` or create an interface `Person` for it with properties name and mobile. Then you can use `Person[]` or `Array<Person>`

Comment: @Nico Van Belle 
i make it but still the same

Comment: i update question with the console print screen @anoop

Comment: @Igor No the array is static and i want to pass it to function

Comment: If that is the question, it's not that well explained I am afraid.. Try `JSON.stringify(x);` to print it.

Comment: @NicoVanBelle thank you very much,it work well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code of sending data is ok, but the problem is with `log`.

Change : `console.log("data in function " + x);`

to `console.log("data in function ", x);`,

as by `+` it's stringyfy the Array, so remove it.